# hazelcast distributed query gives HazelcastSerializationException

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am new to Hazelcast. I'm trying to use distributed query on IMap which in turn stores custom Java object as value (string key). Adding the data to the map is smooth, even getting the data is a piece of cake, but when I try to use predicate I get this beautiful message:

> INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 -
>   540b01c) is CLIENT_CONNECTED Exception in thread "main"
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.hazel.Customer     at
>   com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:46)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:172)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:70)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getTargetObject(CachedQueryEntry.java:103)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:81)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:48)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:130)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:55)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AndPredicate.apply(AndPredicate.java:116)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.queryTheLocalPartition(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:349)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.querySequential(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.queryUsingFullTableScan(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.querySafelyUsingFullTableScan(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:218)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.queryLocalPartitions(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryOperation.run(QueryOperation.java:51)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:375)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:402)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:283)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:268)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:232)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:207)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.createInvocations(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:109)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.invokeOnMembers(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:90)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.call(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:79)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractCallableMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractCallableMessageTask.java:35)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:119)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:99)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
>     at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:111)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:74)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:150)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.collectResults(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:122)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.invokeOnMembers(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:91)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.call(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:79)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractCallableMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractCallableMessageTask.java:35)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:119)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:99)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
>     at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(ClientInvocationFuture.java:74)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(ClientInvocationFuture.java:30)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:158)
>     at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.values(ClientMapProxy.java:1180)
>     at com.test.hazel.SqlQueryMember.main(SqlQueryMember.java:33) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException  at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.ClientExceptionFactory$12.createException(ClientExceptionFactory.java:170)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.ClientExceptionFactory.createException(ClientExceptionFactory.java:622)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.ClientExceptionFactory.createException(ClientExceptionFactory.java:589)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$ResponseThread.handleClientMessage(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:331)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$ResponseThread.process(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:313)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$ResponseThread.doRun(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:306)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$ResponseThread.run(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:283)

here's my masterpiece :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    List<String> addList = new ArrayList<>();
    addList.add("iii.cnt.tll.uu:5701");

    clientConfig.setAddresses(addList);

    HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);


    IMap<String, Customer> map = hz.getMap("map");

    map.put("1", new Customer("peter", true, 36));
    map.put("2", new Customer("john", false, 40));
    map.put("3", new Customer("roger", true, 20));

    Set<Customer> employees = (Set<Customer>) map.values(new SqlPredicate("active AND age < 30"));
    System.out.println("Employees: " + employees);

    Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
}
```

And my complicated DTO:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private String name;
    private boolean active;
    private int age;

    Customer(String name, boolean active, int age) {
        this.active = active;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{"
                + "active=" + active
                + ", id='" + id + '\''
                + ", name='" + name + '\''
                + ", age=" + age
                + '}';
    }
}
```

I'm using 3.7.2 'Hazelcast' release. And yes I have these classes in a Jar which are on classpath on the server node.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution . i am supposed to add classpath on the start.bat file rather than on the environment variables. Thanks